# What is a SWT alternative to Swing JTextArea and Highligther

Tags: swing, migration, swt

I migrate a program from Swing to SWT. I have a simple window implemented using Swing:  javax.swing.JTextArea and import javax.swing.text.Highlighter, which allow a user to highlight words of his interest.

I wonder what the fastest way to implement this functionality in SWT is. I have found that I could use a [eclipe component](http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/beyond-rich-text-tricks-using-) ([here is an example](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Text)) but I think there should be an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/StyledText.html).